# How to change MS-SSTP (RRAS) server port?

Tags: windows, routing, remote-access, sstp

I have a webservice on port 443 and 80 in IIS. I want run SSTP Server on port 8443. How can I change the default port (443) to 8443?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use IIS for web (and therefor system http.sys driver), you can keep using SSTP on port 443 as the [system will allow port sharing](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437733/Demystify-http-sys-with-HttpSysManager) and you don't need to change SSTP port.

System HTTP driver will redirect requests to specific application based on URIs. SSTP listens on a [specific URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-sstp/7e5b2134-b4bf-435a-85bf-bfe0313fd889) and does not interfere with IIS.

Comment: thanks, but i really need to change it

Answer (score 1):

You *officially* can't, as SSTP is handled by http.sys in the kernel.

You should use IIS for hosting, IIS+ARR for any other webservices. Use IIS hostheaders (with or without ARR) and/or with SNI to use any other ports with SSL. This works perfect for 80 and 443. If you have to use other stuff (Apache, Tomcat ...) IIS SSL offloading is pretty fast, too. The only thing you should *not* do is using 443 natively, as it is already used natively by RRAS.

If you can't use hostheaders, please let us know why.

Anyway, there is a unsupported hack to change the MS-SSTP listener:

- Get ownership (and write access) to this registry key:

  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SstpSvc\Parameters\ConfigStore`
- Change `ListenerPort` to whatever you like
- Restart RRAS

The MS-SSTP client is capable of using other ports than 443, just put the port in the hostname (like vpn.mycompany.com:8443).

Be aware that this is not a supported configuration, will expose your machine to various migration- and upgrade issues and may (read: will) be overwritten by Cumulative Update (and some other updates, too).